# VIM: Can enter (a)ppend mode but not (i)nsert mode for a file and getting error when attempting to write

Tags: vim

The error when attempting to write is: `E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set`.

It's only happening with one file for some strange reason and the same issues happen when I delete the file and open it again in vim.

All other files are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Vim uses the `'buftype'` option for special buffers that do not represent files (like sidebars created by plugins such as *NERDTree*), or require special commands to read and write (like *netrw*'s remote FTP access).

You can use `:verbose setlocal buftype?` to find out where this was set. The file may be matching an `:autocmd` pattern that mistakenly triggered a plugin. To be able to write the buffer, you can use `:setlocal buftype=`, but it's better to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only occurs inside a single file, try using the command

```
:set buftype: " "​
```

when inside the file. Not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: I tried that. I can write to the file, but insert mode and paste and many other commands don't work.

Comment: @John Check so all hidden files e.g. backups vim can make are removed. Then delete the file and re-create it.

Comment: Anything besides .swp files? I tried deleting the file and the .swp, still nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't be anything else. Where is the file and what is it's name? Maybe that is relevant.

Comment: docker-compose.yml in /home/ubuntu/projects/project_name; it's never given me trouble before